# Function Parameters to Hash Symbols for Rendering Partials

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, render, helper, partials

I have a lot of Render Helper functions like

```
  def generic_form_datetime_field(f,attribute_name, my_label ,selected_model_instance)
    render(:partial => 'common_partials/generic_form/datetime_field',
           :locals => {:f => f,
                       :attribute_name => attribute_name,
                       :my_label => my_label,
                       :selected_model_instance => selected_model_instance
           })
  end
```

notice the local field is full of duplicate keys and values from function  parameters. What is the best practice around this? Is there a way to get the parameters from the method and put them as keys for the hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### taking hash arguments

You can use a few different syntaxes to pull in named arguments as a hash.  One is using the "double splat":

```
def func(**args)
  puts args
end

func(a: 'aval', b: 3)  # prints {:a=>"aval", :b=>3}
```

Another syntax you will see is:

```
def func(opts={})
  puts opts
end

func(a: 'aval', b: 3)  # prints: {:a=>"aval", :b=>3}
```

More info can be found in this [blog post](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/fun-with-keyword-arguments/).

### filtering the hash

If you want to be defensive, you can use a function that filters collections in general: [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select).  Here's an example of how to only take values from a specified whitelist for hash keys:

```
h = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
whitelist = [:a, :c]
h.select { |k, _| whitelist.include?(k) }  
# result: {:a=>"a", :c=>"c"}
```